# Recover Dynamics CRM 2011 Website

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, xrm

I have accidentally managed to delete the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 web-site from IIS (don't ask how...)

Can anyone recommend an approach to restoring the website?

I am running Roll-up 5, 6, 7, 8 & 12 on-top of the initial installation, however Roll-up 12 does not provide a 'Repair' function through 'Add/Remove Programs'. Furthermore, I cannot repair the base install from the original ISO as a newer version (RU12 I presume) has been installed.

Do I need to uninstall all of the roll-up's and perform a repair on the base installation to re-create the website? then re-apply to roll-ups?

UPDATE: I've just discovered that I can't uninstall Rollup 6....

Also, does Roll-up 12 include all prior roll-ups, or do they need to be applied in order?

Cheers, Nick.

Comment: Did you just remove it from IIS? Did anything else go too?

Comment: I removed IIS and re-installed; in the process, I zapped the contents of my C:\inetpub\wwwroot directory :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest building another machine, installing CRM and applying rollups in same order as you did in broken one. Then you need to:

1. copy IIS site from new machine to old one (I'm not IIS guru but you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493236/how-do-you-migrate-an-iis-7-site-to-another-server) or  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318576/how-can-i-copy-clone-a-site-on-iis7))
2. copy content of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb` (assuming you have used default path during installation) from new server to broken one

I never had to do this, but this is how i would try to bring it back.

Comment: That's the route I'm going down at the moment. CRM install is fine, its just the IIS website that's narked.

Comment: I went for a full rebuild in the end. I could find a realistic way of getting all of the Site configuration onto the narked environment.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it enough to just re-import the organization, based on the database, using the Import Organization Wizard in the deployment manager?